# Linq to entities - include foreach inside query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, foreach

i created the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> allItemNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();


var productNames = from product in entities.tbl_producttype
                               select new { ProductName = product.Name, ProductTitle = product.TitleName };

            foreach (var productName in productNames)
            {
                allItemNames.Add(productName.ProductName, productName.ProductTitle);
            }
```

it works great, but can i make the code shorter by dropping the 'foreach' phrase and make the query do the insert into the dictionary? like some kind of an 'into' phrase of the linq that tells the query to "insert the productName into the first string of the dictionary and the ProductTitle into the second"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can confuse code to make modifications whilst querying. Your current implementation is easily readable and expresses the intent of the loop. As such there is no method on an Enumerable to do this.

On a `List` you could use the `ForEach` method, however the cleanest way would be to use the [LINQ ToDictionary method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx).

```
var productNames = 
 from product in entities.tbl_producttype
  select new { ProductName = product.Name, ProductTitle = product.TitleName };
var allItemNames = 
 productNames 
  .ToDictionary(product => product.ProductName, product => product.ProductTitle);
```

Comment: Just a small caveat: this will select more data from the database (namely, all columns of the tbl_producttype table instead of just Name and TitleName). Probably does not make much difference in this case, but still.

Comment: yes it does make a difference because there are thousands of products, thank you. so if i want to take out only the names and titles, should i take the var first , like i did and then do ToDictionary instead of the foreach ?

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can! Here you will find examples:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/todictionary

in your case:

```
.ToDictionary(v => v.ProductName, v => v.ProductTitle)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `ToDictionary`:

```
allItemNames = productNames.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.ProductTitle)
```

Comment: you wrote a comment in the above first answer, what did you mean by "this will select more data from the database" you mean that the ToDictionary() shouldn't be in the same linq query , only after i get the 'allItemNames' to operate it instead of the foreach?

Comment: ToDictionary lives in the 'linq-to-objects' world (it works on IEnumerable, not IQueryable). That means that before actually creating the dictionary, all data from the source table would be fetched into memory. If you leave the 'select' in place before the ToDictionary, linq to entities can tune the SQL statement to only select those 2 columns.